# Reference: Return type of ... should either be compatible with ..., or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used

Tags: php, php-8.1

In PHP 8.1, the following code, which worked in previous versions:

```php
class Example implements Countable {
    public function count() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Raises a deprecation notice:

> Deprecated: Return type of Example::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

What does this mean, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## Background: Return types and covariance

Since PHP 7.0, it has been possible to specify the *return type* of a function or method, such as `function example(): string` to indicate a function that returns a string. This forms a *contract* that other code can rely on.

For instance, this class promises that the `getList` method will return some kind of `Iterator`:

```
class Base {
    public function getList(): Iterator {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Calling code can be written knowing that if `$foo instanceOf Base` is true, then `$foo->getList() instanceOf Iterator` will also be true.

If you extend the class, you can specify the *same* return type, or *a more specific* return type (a rule known as "covariance"), and the calling code's assumption will still be true:

```
class SubClass extends Base {
    public function getList(): DirectoryIterator {
        // ...
    }
}
$foo = new SubClass;
var_dump($foo instanceOf Base); // true
var_dump($foo->getList() instanceOf Iterator); // true
```

But if you specify a *different* return type, or *no return type at all*, the assumption breaks, so PHP won't allow you to do it:

```
class NotPossible extends Base {
    public function getList(): bool {
        return false;
    }
}
// Fatal error: Declaration of NotPossible::getList(): bool must be compatible with Base::getList(): Iterator
// If the error didn't happen...
$foo = new NotPossible;
var_dump($foo instanceOf Base); // would be true
var_dump($foo->getList() instanceOf Iterator); // would be false!
```

## Backwards compatibility and deprecation

If you add a return type to an existing class or interface, every class extending or implementing *must* also be changed, or it will give the same error as in the `NotPossible` example above.

With the addition of [Union Types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.composite.union) in PHP 8.0, the return types of most internal functions and methods can be specified; but specifying it for any class or interface method not marked `final` would have immediately broken a lot of code.

So, instead, the concept of a "tentative" return type was added: the correct return types were documented, but what would normally be an error is instead the deprecation notice shown in the question.

## The `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` attribute

The extra problem is that a lot of code needs to be able to run on multiple versions of PHP, and some of the added return types aren't valid in versions before 8.0. So, to indicate a *planned* change to the returned type in your code, you can add the special [attribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php) `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]`. This looks like a comment to older versions of PHP, but tells PHP 8.1 not to raise the deprecation notice. Then, once you don't need to support older versions of PHP, you can fix the return type.

## What should you do now?

Firstly, read the message carefully to find out which method you need to change, and what the correct return type is. In the example above:

> Return type of Example::count() ...

This says the `count` method on the `Example` class needs changing ...

> ... should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int ...

... and the expected return type is `int`, as defined on the `Countable` interface

Next, decide what you can do:

- Is the code that needs to change in a library or extension written be someone else? Check if there is a new version available. **Since this is only a deprecation, it's OK to ignore it and give the author time to fix it.**
- Does your class already return the correct type? In our example, yes, `42` is valid for a return type of `int`.
- Can you safely change the return type of the method? If you're working on your own application, the answer is probably "yes", as long as you update classes that `extend` this one. If you're working on library code where users might have extended this class, you will need to consider the impact on them.

If you decide it's safe, you can simply **add the return type** as shown in the notice:

```php
class Example implements Countable {
    public function count(): int {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

If you need to support older versions of PHP, or users who won't have updated their code yet, you can **temporarily** suppress the notice:

```php
class Example implements Countable {
    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function count() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

It's important to note that the internal return types will probably be **enforced in PHP 9.0**, so make sure you have a solid plan to change methods you mark with this attribute.

Comment: I wonder why we don't see this deprication with `Stringable`? https://3v4l.org/Plutn#v8.1.2

Comment: @Rain `Stringable` is a weird special case, which defies the normal rules of the language for reasons I don't really understand. You do however get an error if you provide the _wrong_ return type for `__toString`, regardless of explicitly mentioning the interface: https://3v4l.org/fcNql

Comment: It would be nice to have a worky possibilty to support php5. I would like to see something like: [#\Compat\ReturnType(bool) which makes the deprecation also to go away.

Comment: @giftnuss `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` will "work" fine under PHP 5, because it is seen as a comment. The chances of supporting both PHP 5 and PHP 9 in the same application are pretty slim, though, so if you're really stuck supporting PHP 5 (which [had its final official release over 3 years ago](https://www.php.net/eol.php)), you might be best off just ignoring all deprecations until you can modernise.

Comment: @IMSoP I want to support older windows. The newer PHPs have dropped support for this platform, which is kind of code obsolescence. PHP5 is mostly a nice programming language and being backwards compatible is a  feature, not a bug.

Comment: @giftnuss Absolutely, backwards compatibility is a good thing, and that's why these return types are only going to be enforced in 9.0, not 7.0. Sometimes the only way to do better than that (other than not changing anything) is with a time machine that can change past decisions. If you want your application to run on a wide variety of versions, one option worth considering is using [Rector](https://getrector.org/) to generate parallel versions of the code for you.

Comment: @giftnuss PHP5 is EOL and does not receive any security coverage or patches. Any security vulnerability that exists will likely never receive a fix, even if it's discovered. It's fine to have backwards compatible code, but it's not safe to use PHP5 anymore because it's unsupported.

Comment: This answer is excellent and far exceeds the lengths most users go to to help peers.

Comment: Is there a way to supress such warnings without changing code though? Turning off E_DEPRECATED doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: @Shawn Sounds like you didn't manage to apply the setting. Possibly you have something overriding it, or a custom error handler that ignores the setting.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solve by adding `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` before the functions.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't really say anything that's not in the error message itself, and as my answer explains, this is probably _not_ the right solution if you're just upgrading your own application and don't need to support multiple versions of PHP. There's also no reason to take a screenshot of text; just paste the text into the answer directly.

Comment: As a workaround, it works, and it is one of the options recommended by the very same error reported in the log.

Comment: @RodrigoPolo It is also one of the options discussed in my answer, posted 10 months before this one, using actual text rather than a screenshot. If the answer actually gave more details about a situation where this was the right approach, it might have value; but it does not.

Comment: When I was debugging my code, I was getting this error in this function, and by writing #[ReturnTypeWillChange], I was able to solve it. That's why I just copied and pasted the screenshot because I was seeing this in other functions as well.

Comment: @AashirAzeem OK, but did you understand *why* adding that line fixed it, and *when* this would be the appropriate thing to do? What do you hope a reader of your answer will learn that isn't already in the error message itself, and in the existing answer on this page?